# Yii2 - dynamic min and max value validation rules

Tags: php, yii2

How can I create dynamic min and max validation for specific item?

For buying I am using model **Buy**, and for products I am using model **Products**. I need to implement this rules in the Buy model.

Example - I am looking item with id **12**, and this item have stock of 100 units (this needs to be maximum) and minimum order of 10 (this needs to be minimum).

EDIT:

**Products (item) table:**

```
id
name
stock
minOffer
```

**Buy table:**

```
id
offer
product_id
user_id
```

Offer for buying can't be larger then current stock in the product table.

Comment: It would be nice if you can list all fields in your view and specify each field belonging to which model

Comment: @KiranMuralee - I added table description.

Comment: So you are saying like if item id value equals 12,then stock max should be 100.Why not use a custom validator.

Comment: I need a custom validator, but I need to insert id from the product into the Buy validation. I don't know how to do this. Yet :)

Comment: @sasha.I assume buy is having a relation with the product.So in the buy model,there is a definite product object which you can make use of .If you can show me your Buy and Product models,I will get a clear picture and I would be able to suggest how the custom validation code would be :).

Comment: Even if product object is not there.You can make use of that product id to do a custom validation.If possible please also show me your view(form).I assume when you are buying you are definitely selecting a product in view.

Comment: I have given an answer assuming your conditions,the answer can be modified if you provide me more details about your models and view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your Buy model,you can write your custom rule like one given below.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['product_id', 'checkmaxandminvalues'],//assuming product_id is a field in Buy

            // other rules
        ];
    }

public function checkmaxandminvalues($attribute, $params)
{
    $your_product=Products::find()->where(['_id'=>$this->product_id])->one();

    //Here you do your validation logic
    if($your_product->_id === 12 && $your_product->stock > 100)
    {
        $this->addError('product_id', 'Product stock should not be greater than 100');
    }
   else if($your_product->_id===12 && $your_product->stock < 10)
   {

        $this->addError('product_id', 'Product stock should not be less than 10');
   }
}
```